# Set a column to NOT NULL if there is a value in other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time with designing mysql database.
I need to set a column to NOT NULL if there is a value in some other column.
For example I have the table Student:

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    studentID INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    surname VARCHAR(50),
    age INT,
    address VARCHAR(50),
    school VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_age(age>18)
)
```

I need to set the column surname to NOT NULL if there is a value in column name.
In other words, if the name is NULL surname can also be NULL. But if column name has a value surname needs also to have a value.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a check constraint.

Comment: BTW, never store age. Most people tend to become older every year, and your data will soon be outdated. Store dob instead.

Comment: Can I put an IF ELSE statement in a check constraint? If name is not null THEN surname is NOT NULL?

Comment: You _can_ have a case expression, but in general AND/OR is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Use a check constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_NAMES (surname is not null or name is null)
```

If name is null, the check constraint is valid - no matter what surnamne is.

If name is not null, also surname must be not null.